# The dashbord `Project -> NETWORK -> Network Topology` always loading

Tags: openstack

The `Project -> NETWORK -> Network Topology` always  loading...

[image: image description]

But the  `Project -> NETWORK -> Networks` and `Project -> NETWORK -> Routers` all are good, will shows the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found `nova-compute` service did not start up:

```
[root@ha-node3 mysql]# nova service-list 
+----+------------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| Id | Binary           | Host     | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated_at                 | Disabled Reason |
+----+------------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| 2  | nova-consoleauth | ha-node3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:44:32.000000 | -               |
| 5  | nova-conductor   | ha-node3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:44:32.000000 | -               |
| 7  | nova-cert        | ha-node3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:44:32.000000 | -               |
| 15 | nova-scheduler   | ha-node3 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:44:32.000000 | -               |
| 22 | nova-cert        | ha-node1 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:40.000000 | -               |
| 29 | nova-conductor   | ha-node1 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:40.000000 | -               |
| 32 | nova-consoleauth | ha-node1 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:40.000000 | -               |
| 33 | nova-consoleauth | ha-node2 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:38.000000 | -               |
| 36 | nova-scheduler   | ha-node1 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:41.000000 | -               |
| 40 | nova-conductor   | ha-node2 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:39.000000 | -               |
| 44 | nova-cert        | ha-node2 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:39.000000 | -               |
| 46 | nova-scheduler   | ha-node2 | internal | enabled | up    | 2017-08-06T11:43:48.000000 | -               |
| 49 | nova-compute     | ha-node2 | nova     | enabled | down  | 2017-08-06T08:57:50.000000 | -               |
| 53 | nova-compute     | ha-node1 | nova     | enabled | down  | 2017-08-06T08:57:30.000000 | -               |
+----+------------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

So I restarted the nova-compute service:

```
systemctl start openstack-nova-compute.service
```